# How to get response of Status Command from Thermal printer using Tcp/Ip socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, thermal-printer

i am working on a new  android application that use an (Ethernet) Thermal printer ,the Smartphone and the printer are in the same network (192.168.2.0 ) , so till Here it works fine i can print ticket and send command to the printer successfully, but i am not able to get the satuts of the printer (Paper status for exemple ), i send the command (Socket Outputstream )but i can't read the response (Inputstream ) using Tcp/ip (Socket) , So my question Is , How can i read the response of the printer using Inputstream ?? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you got the answer?

Comment: @Rajesh did you get the answer